# Rendering dynamic search in PDF xhtml2pdf Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am having some problems in rendering a a search query in PDF in Django.
What I am trying to achieve is to print in PDF a web page search (I am filtering some data basically) and print the results in PDF.

I can be more clear with some code.

views.py

```
def total_flight_hours(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    instructors = Instructor.objects.all()
    aircrafts = Aircraft.objects.all()
    start_date = request.POST.get('start_date')
    if not start_date:
        start_date = dt.now().date()
    end_date = request.POST.get('end_date')
    if not end_date:
        end_date = dt.now().date()
    student = request.POST.get('student')
    if not student:
        student = ''
    instructor = request.POST.get('instructor')
    if not instructor:
        instructor = ''
    aircraft = request.POST.get('aircraft')
    if not aircraft:
        aircraft = ''

    log_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
        student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft))
    log_entry_dual = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
        student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft) & Q(solo_flight=False))
    total_flight_hours = log_entry_dual.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('ata') - F('etd'), output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']
    if total_flight_hours != None:
        total_flight_hours = duration(total_flight_hours)
    log_entry_solo = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
        student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft) & Q(solo_flight=True))
    total_flight_hours_solo = log_entry_solo.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
        F('ata') - F('etd'), output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']
    if total_flight_hours_solo != None:
        total_flight_hours_solo = duration(total_flight_hours_solo)

    log_entry_list = zip(log_entry, log_entry_solo)
    student_mission = StudentMission.objects.filter(
        log_entry_id__in=log_entry)

    month_begin = dt.today().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    today = dt.today().date()
    context = {
        'log_entry': log_entry,
        'log_entry_solo': log_entry_solo,
        'total_flight_hours': total_flight_hours,
        'total_flight_hours_solo': total_flight_hours_solo,
        'students': students,
        'instructors': instructors,
        'aircrafts': aircrafts,
        'student_mission': student_mission,
        'log_entry_list': log_entry_list,
        'month_begin': month_begin,
        'today': today
    }
    return render(request, 'flight/total_flight_hours.html', context)
```

The function above is the view for my page, which is working fine. What I'm trying to achieve is to have just the results of this page printed in PDF. I tried to do a view like that:
views.py

```
class GenerateTotalFlightHoursPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template(
            'flight/total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view.html')

        students = Student.objects.all()
        instructors = Instructor.objects.all()
        aircrafts = Aircraft.objects.all()
        start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
        if not start_date:
            start_date = dt.now().date()
        end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
        if not end_date:
            end_date = dt.now().date()
        student = request.GET.get('student')
        if not student:
            student = ''
        instructor = request.GET.get('instructor')
        if not instructor:
            instructor = ''
        aircraft = request.GET.get('aircraft')
        if not aircraft:
            aircraft = ''

        log_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
            student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft))
        log_entry_dual = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
            student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft) & Q(solo_flight=False))
        total_flight_hours = log_entry_dual.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
            F('ata') - F('etd'), output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']
        if total_flight_hours != None:
            total_flight_hours = duration(total_flight_hours)
        log_entry_solo = LogEntry.objects.filter(Q(date__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(
            student_id__id__icontains=student) & Q(instructor_id__id__icontains=instructor) & Q(aircraft_id__id__icontains=aircraft) & Q(solo_flight=True))
        total_flight_hours_solo = log_entry_solo.aggregate(eet=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(
            F('ata') - F('etd'), output_field=IntegerField()), output_field=DurationField()))['eet']
        if total_flight_hours_solo != None:
            total_flight_hours_solo = duration(total_flight_hours_solo)

        log_entry_list = zip(log_entry, log_entry_solo)
        student_mission = StudentMission.objects.filter(
            log_entry_id__in=log_entry)
        context = {
            'log_entry': log_entry,
            'log_entry_solo': log_entry_solo,
            'total_flight_hours': total_flight_hours,
            'total_flight_hours_solo': total_flight_hours_solo,
            'students': students,
            'instructors': instructors,
            'aircrafts': aircrafts,
            'student_mission': student_mission,
            'log_entry_list': log_entry_list,
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf(
            'flight/total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view.html', context)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

The problem is that the PDF file has the template printed but not the query results. I tried to find some information on the internet but I couldn't find anything.
For reference I post also the urls and the pdf template

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.aircraft_home, name='aircraft_home'),
    path('add_aircraft', views.add_aircraft, name='add_aircraft'),
    path('aircraft_list', views.AircraftListView.as_view(), name='aircraft_list'),
    path('add_new_flight', views.add_new_flight, name='add_new_flight'),
    path('edit_flight/<str:pk>', views.edit_flight, name='edit_flight'),
    path('delete_flight/<str:pk>', views.delete_flight, name='delete_flight'),
    path('flight_list', views.FlightListView.as_view(), name='flight_list'),
    path('total_flight_hours', views.total_flight_hours, name='total_flight_hours'),

    # PDF Views
    path('total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view', views.GenerateTotalFlightHoursPDF.as_view(),
         name='total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view')

]
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Aircraft</th>
        <th>Dep. AD</th>
        <th>Arr. AD</th>
        <th>ATD</th>
        <th>ATA</th>
        <th>Tot. Time</th>
        <th>Solo Time</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Student</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for log in log_entry %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{log.date|date:'d-m-Y'}}</td>
        <td>{{log.aircraft}}</td>
        <td>{{log.adep.icao_code}}</td>
        <td>{{log.ades.icao_code}}</td>
        <td>{{log.etd|time:'H:i'}}</td>
        <td>{{log.ata|time:'H:i'}}</td>
        <td>{% if log.solo_flight == False %}{{log.eet|date:'H:i'}}{% endif %}</td>
        <td>{% if log.solo_flight == True %}{{log.eet|date:'H:i'}}{% endif %}</td>
        <td>{{log.instructor.first_name}} {{log.instructor.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{log.student.first_name}} {{log.student.last_name}}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Total Hours</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{total_flight_hours}}</td>
        <td>{% if total_flight_hours_solo != None %}{{total_flight_hours_solo}}{% endif %}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

render_to_pdf

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), 
    content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

Than you very much in advance for your kind help

Comment: Why are you doing `html = template.render(context)`

Comment: That’s a mistake but if I remove it the result doesn’t change. Actually it was just a copy-paste error

Comment: What does your `render_to_pdf` function look like? In your post you show a template. Which one is that, the `total_flight_hours.html` or `total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view.html`. Do you get the table heading in your pdf?

Comment: For the render_to_pdf function, I edited my post. The view for the PDF is total_flight_hours_render_pdf_view.html. I get the table heading in the PDF but not the data in fact.